# vk api [php] Количество друзей

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть код:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=185610037&count&access_token={access_token}&v=5.60';
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
print_r( $users );
?>
```

Выдаёт:

```
stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 1286 [items] => Array ( [0] => 232578 [1] => 342835 [2] => 936371 [3] => 1270059 ...
```

Никак не могу сообразить чтоб выдавало только число `[count]`

Comment: print_r($users->count);

Comment: Здравствуйте, изменил, но теперь просто белый экран
`<?php
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=185610037&count&access_token={access_token}&v=5.60';
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
print_r($users->count);
?>`

Comment: `$users->response->count`

Answer (score 0):

Я решил вопрос, просто воспользовавшись другим методом, вот что получилось:

```
<?php
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id={id}&fields=counters&access_token={token}&v=5.60'. $get_params));
//echo ($result[0])
//echo ($result -> response[0] -> counters[0] -> friends);
print_r($result -> response[0] -> counters -> friends);
?>
```

И он выдаёт именно число.